# how to change the width of the gaps between the panels in facet in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

as title, I have having quite a lot of panels when generating a chart by ggplot, and I think the gap is a bit too wide, can I adjust it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you want.

```
+ opts(panel.margin = unit(0, "inches"))
```